# jquery select2 .on("change", function(e) reset option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i am using select2.

Usage : if a value is `"COUNTRY"`, i want to add a onchange event to the select2, else i want to remove the onchange event as shown below :

```
var reportLevel = getReportLevel();

if (reportLevel != "COUNTRY") {
    $("#selected_countries").on("change", function(e) {
        prepareGlidModel(e);
    });
} else {
    $("#selected_countries").on("change", function(e) {
    });
}
```

Issue : Not being able to remove the onchange event, even if the else block is called.
Events are called based upon the `reportLevel` value selected in a `dropdown`.

Comment: For remove an event you have to use off instead of on

Comment: hey @Daniele, can you please gimme an example

Comment: I think something like $("#selected_countries").off("change"); Check [jquery off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try following:

```
var reportLevel = getReportLevel(),
    // by default unbind/off change event
    $select = $("#selected_countries").off("change");

// and if country then bind it
if (reportLevel == "COUNTRY") {
   $select.on("change", function(e) {
       alert("you selected :" + $(this).val());
   });
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/JB89B/1/

Comment: Note that you can namespace your events.  Usually not necessary when you are just binding, but when you need to selectively unbind, it can be important.

$select.on('change.myFeature', function (e) { ... });

$select.off('change.myFeature'); // Only removes the above 'change' handler, not any other 'change' handlers.

Answer (score 3):

i think on else case you want to reset the value to default for this you have to use

```
$("#selected_countries").val('default value')
```

and if u just want to prevent the default action of onchange event than on else you can write

```
e.preventDefault()
```

this will help

Comment: can i do something that will remove the onchange handler on the select2

Comment: ya you can do it and the answer for that is allready given to u on top by rodrigo sa rosa

Answer (score 1):

You can use off to deatach event handlers from your elements as shown below:

```
$("#selected_countries").off('change');
```